# Dynamically add Images into viewpager containing ImageView(Individual Pages)

Tags: android, dynamic, android-viewpager, imageview

I want to dynamically add images into ViewPager, using Glide Image Library. I have a CustomPagerAdapter Class:-

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private List<DressDetailResult> mResources;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, List<DressDetailResult> images) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mResources = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.mResources.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_dress_detail_vertical_vp, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_dress_detail_vertical_vp_iv_dress);

        DressDetailResult dressDetailResult = mResources.get(position);

     Log.e("image url detail", " " + dressDetailResult.getImages());

        Glide.with(mContext).load(dressDetailResult.getImages())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
```

And this is my Model Class working with RetroFit 2.0 :-

```
package com.webmavens.sherrihill.models.DressDetail;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class DressDetailResult {


    @SerializedName("images")
    @Expose
    private List<String> images = null;


    public List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<String> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

}
```

Getting Image Urls in List, but don't know how to load it into Glide, even i tried to load using below code, but it only loads one image, and not adding another page for next image:

```
List<String> stringList = dressDetailResult.getImages();

 Glide.with(mContext).load(stringList.get(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);
```

Logcat of Array of ImageUrls is:-

```
    [http://chandrajeet.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/3148608-lg.jpg, 
http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg, 
http://www.thinkstockphotos.in/ts-resources/images/home/TS_AnonHP_462882495_01.jpg,
    http://hdwallpapershdpics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/4237684-images.jpg]
```

I think it loads all of the array into glide, how do i individualize it?

Comment: Pass the images list in adapter. mResources should be array or list of url of images. It will work fine then.

Comment: not getting your point, where do i add? In which line?

Comment: share the api end point

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `instantiateItem` to create item for `viewpager`. You need to declare **final** for all view in this method to keep the instance of page. Should be like this:

```
final View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_dress_detail_vertical_vp, container, false);

final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_dress_detail_vertical_vp_iv_dress);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set up glide library correctly.

All the neccessary steps can be found in this [link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

If you have checked all the boxed for integrating glide library then :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Add this line of code in your manifest file for internet access.

**Additionally**: To avoid several request queue consider passing context to application class (Singleton Design Practice). But just so you know your current context should also do the required job.